# Dead letters on unrelated ActorRefs when sending message from remotely deployed actor

Tags: java, akka, akka-cluster

I ran into a problem where messages to remote actors in an akka-cluster have very high latency (10+ s) after a the application has run for a while. The logs suggest that the provider attempts to resolve old actors `ActorPath`s, which have nothing to do with the `ActorRef` I'm actually sending the messages to. You can find an excerpt from the logs at the bottom of the question.

My application comprises 3 ActorSystems which interact via `akka-cluster`, remote transmission is configured via `artery`, I'll provide my `applications.conf`(s) further down.

I create a remote actor as a child to a local actor programmatically ([like so](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/remoting.html#programmatic-remote-deployment)), and then do the same from the child actor again (therefor ending up with parent-child-grandchild all in different `ActorSystem`s).

If I send a message from the grandchild to its parent right at the start of the application, I do receive the msg with reasonable latency (< 10 ms). I do run all three systems on the same physical machine.

If I however start (and kill) other actors on the three systems, the message latency for such messages becomes impractical. I think it has something to do with one of the `ActorSystem`'s `LocalActorRefProvider`s trying to resolve `ActorPath`s of previously created (and already dead) actors. I'll post an excerpt of the application logs that show something like this happening.

I don't understand why any other references should need to be resolved when I specifically send a message to a (remote) `ActorRef` and would be genuinely grateful for any help or suggestion.

```
// application.conf(s)

akka {
  actor {
    provider = "cluster"
    serializers {
      kryo = "com.twitter.chill.akka.AkkaSerializer"
    }
    serialization-bindings {
      "java.io.Serializable" = kryo
      "akka.actor.Props" = kryo
    }
    enable-additional-serialization-bindings = on
  }
  remote {
    log-sent-messages = on
    log-received-messages = on
    log-remote-lifecycle-events = off
    artery {
      enabled = on
      transport = tcp
      canonical.hostname = "127.0.0.1"  // these obv differ depending on the system
      canonical.port = 7900
    }
  }
  cluster {
    seed-nodes = [  // set in AbstractSystem
      "akka://experiments-master@127.0.0.1:7900"
    ],
    # WARN Don't use auto-down feature of Akka Cluster in production.
    # auto-down-unreachable-after = 10s
  }
  loglevel = "DEBUG"
}
```

```java
// ParentActor.java
public class ParentActor extends ClusterAwareActor {

    public static final String DEFAULT_NAME = "ParentActor";

    public static Props props() {
        return Props.create(TestActor.class, () -> new TestActor());
    }

    TestActor() {}

    private final Instant initTime = Instant.now();


    @Override
    public Receive createReceive() {
        return receiveBuilder()
                .match(ClusterEvent.CurrentClusterState.class, this::handle)
                .match(ClusterEvent.MemberUp.class, this::handle)
                .build().orElse(super.createReceive());
    }

    @Override
    protected void handle(ClusterEvent.CurrentClusterState msg) {
        super.handle(msg);

        Collection<ActorRef> children = this.remoteActorsOf(ChildActor.props(), ChildActor.DEFAULT_NAME, SystemRole.SLAVE, true);
    }
}
```

```java
// excerpt from ClusterAwareActor
// [ ... ]
protected Collection<ActorRef> remoteActorsOf(Props props, String actorName, SystemRole role, boolean skipOwnSystem) {
    Collection<ActorRef> results = Lists.newArrayList();
    Collection<Member> members = this.systemRoleMemberMap.get(role);

    for (Member member : members) {
        if (cluster.selfMember().equals(member) && skipOwnSystem) continue;

        Props remoteProps = props.withDeploy(new Deploy(new RemoteScope(member.address())));

        if (actorName != null) {
            results.add(this.getContext().actorOf(remoteProps, CustomStringUtils.randomActorName(actorName))); // this is just so I don't have name clashes
        } else {
            results.add(this.getContext().actorOf(remoteProps));
        }
    }
    return results;
}
```

```java
// ChildActor.java
public class ChildActor extends ClusterAwareActor {

    public static final String DEFAULT_NAME = "ChildActor";

    public static Props props() {
        return Props.create(TestActorTwo.class, () -> new TestActorTwo());
    }

    TestActorTwo() {}

    private final Instant initTime = Instant.now();

    @Override
    public Receive createReceive() {
        return receiveBuilder()
                .match(ClusterEvent.CurrentClusterState.class, this::handle)
                .match(Messages.PongWithSendTime.class, this::handle)
                .build().orElse(super.createReceive());
    }

    @Override
    protected void handle(ClusterEvent.CurrentClusterState msg) {
        super.handle(msg);
        Collection<ActorRef> children = this.remoteActorsOf(GrandChildActor.props(), SystemRole.SLAVE, true);
        Preconditions.checkState(children.size() == 1);
        Lists.newArrayList(children).get(0).tell(new Messages.PingMessage(), self());
        log().info("[{}] Sent PING at {} ms", DEFAULT_NAME, Duration.between(this.initTime, Instant.now()).toMillis());
    }

    private void handle(Messages.PongWithTime msg) {
        log().info("[{}] Received PONG at {} ms, transmission took ~ {} ms",
                DEFAULT_NAME,
                Duration.between(this.initTime, Instant.now()).toMillis(),
                Duration.between(msg.getSendTime(), Instant.now()).toMillis());
    }
}
```

```
// GrandChildActor.java
public class GrandChildActor extends AbstractLoggingActor {

    public static final String DEFAULT_NAME = "GrandChildActor";

    public static Props props() {
        return Props.create(PongSayer.class, () -> new PongSayer());
    }

    PongSayer() {}

    @Override
    public Receive createReceive() {
        return receiveBuilder()
                .match(Messages.PingMessage.class, this::handle)
                .build().orElse(super.createReceive());
    }

    private void handle(Messages.PingMessage __) {
        getContext().getParent().tell(new Messages.PongWithTime(Instant.now()), self());
    }
}
```

All this works fine (i.e. messages get through reasonably fast) as long as there haven't been other actors created and killed earlier. If this is the case, the transmission of a single message (only wrapping an `Instant`) can take anywhere from 10 to 30 s.

You can see logs from the `ActorSystem` containing the `ChildActor` here:

```
[INFO] [10/05/2019 22:37:12.431] [dispatcher] [akka://app@172.18.5.173:7700/remote/akka/app@172.18.5.173:7900/user/ParenteActor/ChildActor] Created GrandChildActor and sent PingMessage.
[...]
[DEBUG] [10/05/2019 22:37:13.668] [dispatcher] [akka.actor.LocalActorRefProvider(akka://app)] Resolve (deserialization) of path [remote/akka/app@172.18.5.173:7900/user/path/to/other/unrelated/actor] doesn't match an active actor. It has probably been stopped, using deadLetters.
[DEBUG] [10/05/2019 22:37:13.738] [dispatcher] [akka.actor.LocalActorRefProvider(akka://app)] Resolve (deserialization) of path [remote/akka/app@172.18.5.173:7900/user/path/to/other/unrelated/actor] doesn't match an active actor. It has probably been stopped, using deadLetters.
[DEBUG] [10/05/2019 22:37:13.809] [dispatcher] [akka.actor.LocalActorRefProvider(akka://app)] Resolve (deserialization) of path [remote/akka/app@172.18.5.173:7900/user/path/to/other/unrelated/actor] doesn't match an active actor. It has probably been stopped, using deadLetters.
[...] // there is a metric ton of these
[DEBUG] [10/05/2019 22:37:32.498] [dispatcher] [akka.actor.LocalActorRefProvider(akka://app)] Resolve (deserialization) of path [remote/akka/app@172.18.5.173:7900/user/path/to/other/unrelated/actor] doesn't match an active actor. It has probably been stopped, using deadLetters.
[DEBUG] [10/05/2019 22:37:32.568] [dispatcher] [akka.actor.LocalActorRefProvider(akka://app)] Resolve (deserialization) of path [remote/akka/app@172.18.5.173:7900/user/path/to/other/unrelated/actor] doesn't match an active actor. It has probably been stopped, using deadLetters.
[DEBUG] [10/05/2019 22:37:32.638] [dispatcher] [akka.actor.LocalActorRefProvider(akka://app)] Resolve (deserialization) of path [remote/akka/app@172.18.5.173:7900/user/path/to/other/unrelated/actor] doesn't match an active actor. It has probably been stopped, using deadLetters.
[DEBUG] [10/05/2019 22:37:32.708] [dispatcher] [akka.actor.LocalActorRefProvider(akka://app)] Resolve (deserialization) of path [remote/akka/app@172.18.5.173:7900/user/path/to/other/unrelated/actor] doesn't match an active actor. It has probably been stopped, using deadLetters.
// before finally
[INFO] [10/05/2019 22:37:32.711] [dispatcher] [akka://app@172.18.5.173:7700/remote/akka/app@172.18.5.173:7900/user/ParentActor/ChildActor] Received Lookup response. Transmission took 20234 ms.
```

Answer (score 0):

With the incomplete and redacted information it's impossible to pinpoint the exact answer, however Akka doesn't try to resolve unrelated ActorRefs. That message indicates that another node of the cluster actually is sending messages to those dead actors.

Regarding the time: the code you show measures the time between the parent's start and the reception of any pong message, which given the trigger via a cluster message could be an arbitrary timespan.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Since this is part of a bigger codebase, I'll put together an MWE and link it here.

Re. the time measurement: The triggering message is the Ping sent from the Child to the GrandChild right after the latter's instantiation. This in turn happens upon receiving the CurrentClusterState event. Also I log (an estimate of) the transmission time by comparing the time when GrandChild sends the message to when Child receives it.